# Existe alguma forma (viável) de desenvolver softwares para Windows em Linux? Alguma aplicação para tal?

Tags: c++, linux, api, windows, cross-platform

Eu estou tentando criar uma aplicação cross-plataform (por motivos académicos), que pelo menos funcione em windows e em Linux. Para o desenvolvimento só poderei utilizar bibliotecas padrão do c/c++ e a API nativa de cada plataforma (WinAPI e X11).

O problema é que, desta forma, eu terei que trocar de sistema cada vez que eu quiser testar o meu código. Ou desenvolver no windows no Visual c++ (pois o visual c++ suporta desenvolvimento para Linux). Mas nenhuma das opções me agrada (desenvolver em windows, por vários motivos, me causa dores de cabeça enormes), bom mesmo seria fazer tudo no Linux.

Gostaria que me dissessem, neste caso, o que seria o melhor a fazer?

Comment: Eu recomendo um livro muito bom, Windows System Programming. Acho que está na 4a. edição e ele aborda isso. Mas o livro tem sotaque em C.

Comment: eu não gosto muito mas uma virtual machine serve perfeitamente

Comment: https://www.qt.io/

Comment: [`mingw-w64`](http://mingw-w64.org)